# Kendo Dropdown initial Value is lost if initial value is outside of default remote data returned

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a Kendo dropdown performing a remote lookup on a table. It is set to only return the first 50 results when the dropdown is expanded so as to not load a ridiculous amount of data. Results beyond that are loaded in when searching for a specific matching term.

The initial saved value shows OK having been set by the text and value parameters. But as soon as the dropdown is expanded the value is wiped.

I have put together an example below:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/remotedatasource">
        <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />
    
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
        
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
            <div id="example">
                
                <div class="demo-section k-content">
                    <h4>Products</h4>
                    <input id="products" style="width: 100%" />
                </div>
    
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#products").kendoDropDownList({
                            dataTextField: "ProductName",
                            dataValueField: "ProductID",
                            dataSource: {
                                transport: {
                                    read: {
                                        dataType: "jsonp",
                                        url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products",
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            filter: "contains",
                            value: 500,
                            text: "Result Outside Of Initial Scope",
                            autoBind: false,
                            "optionLabel": "Please select ..." 
                        });
                    });
                </script>
    
            </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Because the initial value of 500 is not returned (the query returns just under 80 results) the initial value gets wiped.

**How do I stop the value from getting wiped on expand?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked it out. I need to use the "requestEnd" event :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/remotedatasource">
        <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />
    
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
        
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
            <div id="example">
                
                <div class="demo-section k-content">
                    <h4>Products</h4>
                    <input id="products" style="width: 100%" />
                </div>
    
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#products").kendoDropDownList({
                            dataTextField: "ProductName",
                            dataValueField: "ProductID",
                            dataSource: {
                                transport: {
                                    read: {
                                        dataType: "jsonp",
                                        url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products",
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            filter: "contains",
                            value: 500,
                            text: "Result Outside Of Initial Scope",
                            autoBind: false,
                            "optionLabel": "Please select ..." 
                        });
                      
                      $("#products").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.bind("requestEnd", function (e) {
                        
                        var add = true;

                        e.response.forEach(function (element) {

                            var exists = (element.Value == "500)");

                            if (exists) {

                                add = false;
                            }
                          
                        });


                        if (add) {

                          e.response.push({

                              ProductName: "Result Outside Of Initial Scope",
                              ProductID: "500"
                          });

                        } 
                        
                      });
                      
                      
                    });
                </script>
    
            </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the code snippet below:-
-> Handle the open and change events on this save the selected text and value to variables
-> Handle the close events on this set the saved values back to the dropdown list
Here we need to add it to the datasource so that it displays in the drop down

```
<div id="example">

    <div class="demo-section k-content">
        <h4>Products</h4>
        <input id="products" style="width: 100%" />
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var selectedValue = 500;
            var selectedText = 'PRODUCT 500';

            function getDropDownList() {
                var ddl= $("#products").data("kendoDropDownList");
                selectedValue = ddl.value();
                selectedText = ddl.text();
            };

            function setDropDownList() {
                var ddl= $("#products").data("kendoDropDownList");
                var dataItem = ddl.dataSource.get(selectedValue);
                if(dataItem == undefined){
                    ddl.dataSource.add({ ProductName: selectedText,  ProductID: selectedValue});
                }
                ddl.value(selectedValue)
            };

            $("#products").kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: "ProductName",
                dataValueField: "ProductID",
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            dataType: "jsonp",
                            url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products",
                        }
                    },
                serverFiltering: true,
                schema: {
                        model: { id: "ProductID" }
                }
                },
                filter: "contains",
                value: selectedValue,
                text: selectedText,
                            change: getDropDownList,
                            close: setDropDownList,
                            open: getDropDownList,
                autoBind: false,
                "optionLabel": "Please select ..." 
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: I have multiple dropdowns on the page so using global variables is a no go. Any other thoughts? Anyway of amending this to support multiple dropdown on a page?